# Customize Gnome Archive Manager 7z commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, 7zip

Archive manager + nautilus is very usefull thing for any work with archives

If you install p7zip-full package Archive manager can work with 7z archives

But Archive manager use default settings for compressing

It is very bad

Classical example with javadoc:

Download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

```
unzip jdk-6u23-docs.zip
mv docs javadoc

7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -ms=on javadoc.7z javadoc
du -chb javadoc.7z
    24791075    javadoc.7z
```

But from man 7z and from LzmaLib.h we know that best compression is `-mx=9 -mfb=273 -md=64m`

Let's try:

```
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=273 -md=64m -ms=on javadoc.7z javadoc
du -chb javadoc.7z
    21308619    javadoc.7z
```

This is real better!

Question:
How to make Archive manager to use custom 7z command as default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get a faster answer at [superuser](https://superuser.com/), for questions like this one.

Looking at the program, I discovered that it was [File-Roller](http://fileroller.sourceforge.net/feedback.html) and the compression parameters were in an XML file.  The manual mentioned nothing about configuration for the compression level.  Finally, I found this information with Google(at bottom of page):

> [Veikk0 wrote on the 24 Jul 10 at 20:17](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/3520)
>      In my opinion this should get more
>   attention. Creating archives can be
>   frustrating and difficult at the
>   moment, mostly because to change the
>   compression level you have to:
>
> 1. Open gconf-editor (alt+F2 or from terminal).
> 2. Navigate to /apps/file-roller/general
> 3. Manually edit the key called compression_level to very_fast, fast,
>      normal or maximum.
> 4. Create your archive with file-roller.
> 5. Repeat if you want to create another archive with different
>      compression level.

Furthermore, there's a bug for this: [Bug 450019 - compression level](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=450019)

Answer (score 1):

On Trisquel 6.0/Ubuntu 12.04, it's `dconf-editor`, and the schema is `org.gnome.FileRoller.General`.

The best compression with 7-zip can be achieved with

```
7zr a -mx=9 OUTPUT.7z INPUT
```

which produces slightly smaller files than the "maximum" compression level of File Roller, due to the fact, that File Roller uses the `-m0=lzma2` parameter, which is no longer beneficial as of 7-zip version 9.20.